# Accesing webapps folder in tomcat in uubuntu

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to deploy a war inside tomcat running on ubuntu. But, unable to access webapps folder.

My tomcat user is 'tomcat'.

Plz tell me how Can I get inside Webapps and dump my war's?

Image below:
[image]

Comment: Check your /opt/tomcat folder ownership. It should be same as tomcat.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain text when you post textual content, not images